# How can I access information from /proc/net/tcp from code running in a k8s pod?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, network-programming, prometheus, netstat

I'm currently trying to export prometheus metrics for TCP-related stats - that which can be found by polling /proc/net/tcp - and I'm finding that the sockets returned within the context of my main container process do NOT include those exposed by the docker container for my service code. I'm primarily interested in the status of TCP connections relating to the ports exposed by my service, but those seem inexplicably missing.

I'm leveraging a library from the prometheus project ([procfs](https://github.com/prometheus/procfs/tree/master)) and the sockets returned from the [NetTCP()](https://github.com/prometheus/procfs/blob/b6ad5a772afe33c7d1e769ccc7eb12bdc850536e/net_tcp.go#L28) function, which effectively reads /proc/net/tcp, does not include information related to the ports I'm exposing for my service code.

Conversely, running `kubectl exec <pod> -- netstat -tulpn` *does* show the sockets associated with my exposed ports.

Can anyone provide insight regarding why the sockets of interest are not included in the results from /proc/net/tcp when reading it from service code?

Tried:

Called [NetTCP()](https://github.com/prometheus/procfs/blob/b6ad5a772afe33c7d1e769ccc7eb12bdc850536e/net_tcp.go#L28)  to inspect TCP information from within my service code

Expected:

Sockets information for the ports exposed by my service

Actual:

Sockets information for other processes/ports, but *not* for the ports exposed by my service.